# nginx 504,can't connet mysql

Tags: mysql, nginx, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn, http-status-code-504

Environment:

```
python 3.6
flask
flask-sqlalchemy
mysql
gunicorn
nginx
```

Phenomenon:

1. If I run gunicorn and nginx, and connect service http address, can't connect and show 504 time-out error.
2. If I only run `python flask(0.0.0.0)`, I can connect succeessful.
3. If I firstly `run python flask(0.0.0.0)`, and `shutdown` it. Next, I run `gunicorn` and nginx, I can connect successful.
4. But, after about 2 or 3 hours, I can't connect `http (504 error)` again. So, I must repet step3.

Try measure: add send\read time and increase buffer size in nginx conf. But that doesn't work also.

I guess the `sqlalchemy` or `mysql` are causing this problem because it works perfectly if I don't use either of these libraries.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: what was error when you got 504 ?

Comment: 504 gate time out

Comment: I mean the flask log, I don't understans step 3, you run python flask then shutdown it ?

Comment: yes,i mean, run python flask.py and ctrl+c close it.  (it's so weird)

Comment: i recommend that you use supervisor to control gunicorn. I use this as an example for that: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux